# SQL query in 10 minute interval

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table

> 2014-01-07 12:35:01 data1 data2 data3 data4 data5
>
> 2014-01-07 12:35:02 data1 data2 data3 data4 data5
>
> 2014-01-07 12:35:02 data1 data2 data3 data4 data5
>
> 2014-01-07 12:35:03 data1 data2 data3 data4 data5
>
> 2014-01-07 12:35:04 data1 data2 data3 data4 data5

and so on..
I execute following query

```
select * from test
```

but I want query output after the interval of 10 minutes. For example in the query output first row will be at
2014-01-07 12:35:01 and then second will be at 2014-01-07 12:36:01 and so on. How can I do it using sql queries only?

Comment: Not fully sure what you're trying to do here?

Comment: Cron (linux) or Windows scheduler. (And you give it task with interval)

Comment: select * from test output will be all rows in test table but in the output I want rows at 10 minutes interval.

Comment: Yes, but do you want to return only 1 row each time or should it return all rows but in each row 10 minutes will be added to the time? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: yes I have written so on which means I want each row with at 10 minute interval.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some like Cronjob. Check with your webhost, to see if they support it.